# Estimate $\langle ab^\dagger \rangle$ from $\langle a c^\dagger \rangle$ and $\langle c b^\dagger \rangle$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-entanglement

I have three operators, $A$, $B$ and $C$, acting on different systems (which might be correlated/entangled).

I would like to evaluate, or bound, the correlator $\vert\langle A B^\dagger \rangle\vert$, based only on correlators between $A$ and $C$, or $B$ and $C$. Do you know how this can be done?

It might be that I can make some assumptions on the correlations with $C$ (e.g. uncorrelated from $AB$), but I would like first to keep the result as general as possible.

To make a concrete example, consider three harmonic oscillators, where $A=a$, $B=b$, $C=c$, are the associated annihilation operators. I want to compute (or upper/lower bound) $\langle ab^\dagger \rangle$, only using terms like $\langle ac^\dagger \rangle$, $\langle c b^\dagger \rangle$, ... Eventually, I could consider the special assumptions where $c$ is a classical field amplitude ($\langle ac^\dagger \rangle = \langle a \rangle c^\ast$), or an uncorrelated system ($\langle ac^\dagger \rangle = \langle a \rangle \langle c^\dagger \rangle$).

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I would like an expression like $\vert \langle a b^\dagger \rangle \vert \geq \vert \langle a c^\dagger \rangle \vert \vert \langle c b^\dagger \rangle \vert / \langle c^\dagger c \rangle$. Something of this kind: a bound on $\vert \langle a b^\dagger \rangle \vert$, based on the other correlators $ac$, $bc$.

Comment: Wouldn't a first question be: "Is a bound of that kind even possible"?  (Also, "I would like to have" is still not a question.) -- Did you try to cook up counterexamples to such bounds?  Without further restrictions/conditions, there should be quite some room to play with that.